# SQL Query in Rails 5 controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need help creating the following query in rails 5 controller. Could you please help me resolve this?

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE test(ID INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

Comment: That should be done in a migration, not in a controller.

Comment: Agreed with @sawa, you should follow this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

Comment: Yes that I know..Is there is any way to create the table from the controller..Because I need to create the table name based upon the name given in the input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: It is bad to perform SQL operations from controller.

There is provision to run raw SQL queries with ActiveRecord.

Here, it will be like:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE test(ID INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (ID))"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```